# Why does Anorm's executeInsert complain about converting from BigDecimal?

Tags: playframework-2.0, derby, anorm

I am using a Derby database with Anorm in Play 2.0.2.  Even though no column has a `BigDecimal` field, I get the following error when inserting into a table.

> Execution exception [[RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 1:class java.math.BigDecimal to Long for column .1)]]

If I look in the table, I can see that my data *has been entered* so I infer that the problem has to do with returning the new key.  But I clearly declare the key as a `bigint`--why the complaint about `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Derby [always returns the key as a `BigDecimal`](http://code.google.com/p/orbroker/wiki/Gotchas)--even if they key is defined otherwise.  The solution is to use a custom `ResultSetParser` to handle the `BigDecimal`.  The id column returned is named "1".

```
  def idResultSetParser(implicit extractor: anorm.Column[java.math.BigDecimal]) =
    ResultSetParser.singleOpt[java.math.BigDecimal](
      anorm.SqlParser.get[java.math.BigDecimal]("1"))
```

Or, putting it all together.

```
  import java.math.BigDecimal
  s.executeInsert[Option[BigDecimal]](
      ResultSetParser.singleOpt[BigDecimal](
          anorm.SqlParser.get[BigDecimal]("1")))
```

You can then map it to a `Long` with `map (_.longValue)`.